# Wordpress Ajax returns a 404 error

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, wordpress

I want to develop a Wordpress plugin. So, I want to call Ajax function when I click on button in my php code.

This is my php code:

```
function unilang_translation_page() {

            echo '<div class="wrap"><h1>Translations of strings</h1> </div>'; 

            $unilang_table_strings = new Unilang_Table_Strings;
            $unilang_table_strings->prepare_items(); 
            $unilang_table_strings->display();

            $_SESSION['store_table_strings'] = serialize( $unilang_table_strings );

            echo "<a type='button' class=\"button button-primary\" onClick=\"Utility.saveStringTranslations();\">Submit Changes</a>";
}
```

And this is my javascript file:

```
var Utility = {

    saveStringTranslations: function() {
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "/unilang/php/unilang-save-string-translations.php",
            success: function(data) {
                alert(data);
            },
            error: function(error) {
                alert(error);
            }
        })
    }
}
```

When I click on the button the browser console returns this:
[image]

I tried to change path but it doesn't works.
How can I set my plugin path in the URL?

Comment: What happens if you open that Url in your browser?

Comment: Have you read this yet? [AJAX in Plugins - WordPress Codex](https://codex.wordpress.org/AJAX_in_Plugins).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try declaring a JavaScript variable in your plugin PHP file like below

```
<script> var plugin_url = '<?php echo plugins_url( '/unilang/php/unilang-save-string-translations.php', __FILE__ ) ?>'; </script>
```

and call the `plugin_url` variable in the AJAX URL path - `url: plugin_url + "/unilang/php/unilang-save-string-translations.php"`.

Hope this helps and you can read more here - https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/plugins_url.

Comment: Perhaps it will work. However when you are trying to complete AJAX request in WordPresss you need to use the following actions: wp_ajax_nopriv and wp_ajax. And send requests only to  admin-ajax.php. Sending requests to custom php files is not secure way.

Comment: @Outsource WordPress it works! But now console returns this: "POST, 500 internal server error".

Comment: Can you check your server's error log and let me know the error?